# Extended definition of unambiguous language and the existence of unambiguous grammar

Tags: computer-science, it.information-theory, formal-languages

Let's extend the unambiguity of language and grammar as follows:
a language $L$ is unambiguous if there is a grammar that generates every word in $L$ in a unique way, the grammar may be of type 0 or any kind from type 0-3.
A grammar $G$ is unambiguous if the grammar generates every word in a unique way, the grammar may be of type 0 or any kind from type 0-3.

Question:for any given language, is there a unambiguous grammar $G$?

Comment: If you used recursively-enumerable, context-sensitive, context-free and regular instead of type 0-3, it would be a lot easier to understand your question, as those terms are much more commonly used in language theory.

Comment: Certainly, this is not possible for any given language $L$, as there are languages which can't be expressed as a Turing Machine (and thus, not as a type 0 grammar).
Every recursively-enumerable language can be accepted by a deterministic Turing machine, so if you could find an unambiguous unrestricted grammar to simulate a Turing machine, then every $RE$ language could be expressed this way. I don't know if such a thing is possible though.

Comment: As far as I can see, the straightforward way to simulate a deterministic TM by a grammar is indeed unambiguous, so the answer should be yes for every r.e. language.

Comment: @J.-E. Pin,thank you for your editing